# Is there a difference between "scaffold" and "scaffolding"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage

Apparently **scaffolding** is always a substantive while **scaffold** can be used both as substantive and as verb (to scaffold).

I'm interested in the *substantive* meaning of both words.

Google image searching yields pretty much the same results. Are there any differences in meaning or usage?

Comment: Scaffold is an object, a part of whole, of a system called scaffolding. That's the usual usage.

Comment: @Kris, agreed. In my experience, *scaffold* is a count noun and *scaffolding* a mass noun. You could say "*a scaffold*" but you could *not* say "*a scaffolding*".

Comment: If this http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scaffold answers the OP's question, then it's GR.

Comment: @Kris: Doesn't your link state the opposite? "scaffold (plural scaffolds) A structure made of scaffolding, [...]"

Comment: @RomanReiner Scaffolding is also the material used to build a scaffold.

Answer (score 3):

This answer only deals with American English. We have another answer giving the British definitions.

In their first definitions of each word, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scaffold) defines a *scaffold* as the platform that workers stand on (e.g., when working on tall buildings), and *scaffolding* as the structure that supports it.

They have a second definition saying that *scaffold* can also be used for the supporting structure, but they don't say that *scaffolding* can be used for the platform.

I've certainly heard both *scaffolding* and *scaffold* for the supporting structure. And *scaffolding* for the actual platform feels wrong to me, while *scaffold* doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "scaffold" refers only to a gibbet used to hang people. For all other senses I would use "scaffolding" (or, colloquially, "scaff").

Comment: ODO: "2 A structure made using scaffolding. *When setting a plank between ladders as a scaffold, be sure it extends a foot on each side ...* " http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scaffold See also: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scaffolding

Comment: Agreed with Colin Fine. I've only encountered 'scaffold' as a noun when referring specifically to gibbets.

Comment: This must be a US/UK difference, because *"scaffold"* is a perfectly acceptable term for *"scaffolding"* in the US, and I don't think we ever use *"scaff"*.

Comment: My experience may be atypical, because I have worked in theatres for many years, and we often use "scaff" for building sets.